# extension statistic mysql and tcl

Tags: mysql, tcl

I asked a question and received a great solution from @O. Jones, thank you very much.

[Statistics With Tcl And Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864383/statistics-with-tcl-and-mysql)

Unfortunately I had to expand the mysql datanbank with a column building

I need now in addition, name to each, the building, the most benutt

as an example, at work1, A1 is the most used building, at work2 is B1

```
ID  key         ctime       name    floor   floorid door    building
1   114554737   1609613062  work1   1       D1      112     A1
2   114554737   1609662335  work1   1       D1      112     A1
3   114554737   1609662388  work1   1       D1      115     A2
4   114554737   1609665480  work1   2       D1      201     C1
5   114554738   1609701179  work2   2       D1      202     A1
6   114554738   1609701188  work2   1       D1      101     B1
7   114554738   1609701195  work2   2       D1      225     B1
8   114554738   1609701253  work2   3       D1      318     B1
9   114554738   1609707953  work2   4       D1      412     C1
10  114554738   1609876824  work2   5       D1      500     C1
11  114554739   1609956064  work3   1       D1      100     C1
12  114554739   1609956067  work3   1       D1      101     A1
13  114554739   1610084925  work3   1       D1      100     A1
14  114554739   1610084928  work3   1       D1      100     A1
15  114554740   1610141106  work4   2       D1      201     A1
16  114554740   1610141109  work4   2       D1      202     A1
17  114554740   1610177322  work4   2       D1      202     A1
18  114554740   1610178412  work4   2       D1      202     A1
19  114554740   1610207104  work4   2       D1      202     A1
20  114554741   1610216851  work5   2       D1      202     A1
21  114554741   1610268582  work5   2       D1      202     A1
22  114554741   1610268908  work5   2       D1      202     A1
23  114554741   1610271923  work5   2       D1      206     A1
24  114554741   1610275117  work5   2       D1      206     A1
25  114554741   1610293137  work5   3       D1      301     A1
```

I use this query from the answer from O. Jone

```
 set sql {SELECT t.name, t.total, d.details
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) total, name FROM stats GROUP BY name) t
   JOIN (  SELECT name, 
                  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(bydoor,'X',' door ', door) ORDER BY bydoor DESC) details
             FROM (   SELECT COUNT(*) bydoor,
                             name,
                             door
                        FROM stats
                       GROUP BY name, door
                  ) s
            GROUP BY name
         ) d ON t.name = d.name
   ORDER BY t.total DESC, t.name}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Prblem with the count of objects is, what to do if there are two buildings with the same count.

I changed the data to demonstrate the problem.

`GORUP_CONCAT` has also the possibility to order by any column available

for example `GROUP_CONCAT(`building`ORDER BY`building`) AS` building``

> ```
> CREATE TABLE stats (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `key` INTEGER,
>   `ctime` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(5),
>   `floor` INTEGER,
>   `floorid` VARCHAR(2),
>   `door` INTEGER,
>   `building` VARCHAR(2)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO stats
>   (`ID`, `key`, `ctime`, `name`, `floor`, `floorid`, `door`, `building`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '114554737', '1609613062', 'work1', '1', 'D1', '112', 'A1'),
>   ('2', '114554737', '1609662335', 'work1', '1', 'D1', '112', 'A1'),
>   ('3', '114554737', '1609662388', 'work1', '1', 'D1', '115', 'A2'),
>     ('3', '114554737', '1609662388', 'work1', '1', 'D1', '115', 'A2'),
>   ('4', '114554737', '1609665480', 'work1', '2', 'D1', '201', 'C1'),
>   ('5', '114554738', '1609701179', 'work2', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('6', '114554738', '1609701188', 'work2', '1', 'D1', '101', 'B1'),
>   ('7', '114554738', '1609701195', 'work2', '2', 'D1', '225', 'B1'),
>   ('8', '114554738', '1609701253', 'work2', '3', 'D1', '318', 'B1'),
>   ('9', '114554738', '1609707953', 'work2', '4', 'D1', '412', 'C1'),
>   ('10', '114554738', '1609876824', 'work2', '5', 'D1', '500', 'C1'),
>   ('11', '114554739', '1609956064', 'work3', '1', 'D1', '100', 'C1'),
>   ('12', '114554739', '1609956067', 'work3', '1', 'D1', '101', 'A1'),
>   ('13', '114554739', '1610084925', 'work3', '1', 'D1', '100', 'A1'),
>   ('14', '114554739', '1610084928', 'work3', '1', 'D1', '100', 'A1'),
>   ('15', '114554740', '1610141106', 'work4', '2', 'D1', '201', 'A1'),
>   ('16', '114554740', '1610141109', 'work4', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('17', '114554740', '1610177322', 'work4', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('18', '114554740', '1610178412', 'work4', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('19', '114554740', '1610207104', 'work4', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('20', '114554741', '1610216851', 'work5', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('21', '114554741', '1610268582', 'work5', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('22', '114554741', '1610268908', 'work5', '2', 'D1', '202', 'A1'),
>   ('23', '114554741', '1610271923', 'work5', '2', 'D1', '206', 'A1'),
>   ('24', '114554741', '1610275117', 'work5', '2', 'D1', '206', 'A1'),
>   ('25', '114554741', '1610293137', 'work5', '3', 'D1', '301', 'A1');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     t.name, t.total, d.details, t1.`building`
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         COUNT(*) total, name
>     FROM
>         stats
>     GROUP BY name) t
>         JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         name,
>             GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(bydoor, 'X', ' door ', door)
>                 ORDER BY bydoor DESC) details
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         COUNT(*) bydoor, name, door
>     FROM
>         stats
>     GROUP BY name , door) s
>     GROUP BY name) d ON t.name = d.name
>         INNER JOIN
>     (SELECT 
>         `name`,
>             GROUP_CONCAT(`building`) AS `building`,
>             buildingcount
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         `name`, `building`, COUNT(`building`) buildingcount
>     FROM
>         stats s
>     GROUP BY name , `building`
>     HAVING buildingcount = (SELECT 
>             COUNT(`building`)
>         FROM
>             stats
>         WHERE
>             `name` = s.`name`
>         GROUP BY name , `building`
>         ORDER BY COUNT(`building`) DESC
>         LIMIT 1)) t3
>     GROUP BY `name` , buildingcount) t1 ON t1.`name` = t.`name`
> ORDER BY t.total DESC , t.name
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | total | details                                                                 | building
> :---- | ----: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------
> work2 |     6 | 1X door 500,1X door 412,1X door 318,1X door 225,1X door 202,1X door 101 | B1      
> work5 |     6 | 3X door 202,2X door 206,1X door 301                                     | A1      
> work1 |     5 | 2X door 115,2X door 112,1X door 201                                     | A2,A1   
> work4 |     5 | 4X door 202,1X door 201                                                 | A1      
> work3 |     4 | 3X door 100,1X door 101                                                 | A1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `name`,GROUP_CONCAT(`building`), buildingcount
> FROM
> (SELECT  `name`, `building`,COUNT(`building`) buildingcount
> FROM stats s
> GROUP BY name,`building`
> HAVING buildingcount = (SELECT COUNT(`building`) FROM stats WHERE  `name` = s.`name`
> GROUP BY name,`building`
> ORDER BY COUNT(`building`) DESC LIMIT 1)) t3
> GROUP BY `name`, buildingcount
> ```

> ```
> name  | GROUP_CONCAT(`building`) | buildingcount
> :---- | :----------------------- | ------------:
> work1 | A1,A2                    |             2
> work2 | B1                       |             3
> work3 | A1                       |             3
> work4 | A1                       |             5
> work5 | A1                       |             6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=31c8f91e906cf7b533cd20a39d9694da)*

Comment: that's enough for me, big thnks